# colored shadows for transparent objects with shadow catcher

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency, shadows

I'm rendering a scene in cycles with partially transparent objects and I would like to use shadow catcher to composite the objects and their shadows onto a perfectly white background.

Normally these transparent objects cast colored shadows. 
[image]

However, when I make the plane they are sitting on a shadow catcher the shadows are just grey. 
[image]

Is there any way to keep the colored shadows when using the shadow catcher?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible at this point with just the shadow catcher function added in v2.79.

The function is imperfect for compositing, it also does not catch light or refraction/reflections for example. 
Its just a quick way to composite your scene for mock-up purposes.

I would suggest to use the compositor and render passes to achieve the desired effect, which is much more involved and exceeds the answer to this question.